# appStoreReceiptURL == nil after restoreCompletedTransactions()

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, subscription

SKPaymentQueue's `restoreCompletedTransactions()` does not update the appStoreReceiptURL receipt after completion.

I am working on a Mac app that will be supported via auto-renewing subscriptions. After restoring purchases finishes, I need the updated receipt because I will need to check the current subscription status (expiration date, etc.).

The only solution I could come up with was to refresh the receipt right after restore completed transactions finished, as shown below. This does appear to work. However, the user will be prompted to enter in their username and password twice, which is a less than a perfect experience. In addition, I am concerned that such behavior will lead to a rejection by app review.

```
public func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
    if !fileExistsAtAppStoreReceiptURL() {
        print("No receipt.")
    }

    let refreshRequest = SKReceiptRefreshRequest(receiptProperties: nil)
    refreshRequest.delegate = self
    refreshRequest.start()
}

private func fileExistsAtAppStoreReceiptURL() -> Bool {
    guard let appStoreReceiptURL = Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL else { return false }
    return FileManager().fileExists(atPath: appStoreReceiptURL.path)
}

public func requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) {
    if request is SKReceiptRefreshRequest {
        updateCachedReceiptFromAppStoreReceiptURL()
        reverifyKnownPurchases()

        notify { self.delegate?.inAppPurchaseController(self, restoreCompletedTransactionsDidFinishWith: .success) }
    } else {
        notify { self.delegate?.inAppPurchaseController(self, didFinishRequestingIndividualProductInformationWith: .success) }
    }
}
```

Some other notes:

1. `No receipt.` does show up in the log.
2. Because this behavior occurs when using the sandbox environment, I don't know if the behavior is the same when the code executes in production.
3. The behavior did not change after an attempt with a newly-created test user.
4. Because I wanted to simulate a real-life situation, I restored purchases on a second Mac, and not the Mac that purchased the subscription.
5. The rest of the restore process appears to work correctly. `paymentQueue:updatedTransactions:` is called for each restored transaction with a transactionState of .restored.
6. `SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)` is called for each restored transaction.
7. `SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)` is called in applicationDidFinishLaunching:.
8. Although I am making use of an auto-renewing subscription, it does not play a role. A receipt does not appear even if I make use of a non-consumable, for example.
9. I am not using a server.
10. The [Restoring Purchased Products](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html) and the [restoreCompletedTransactions()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skpaymentqueue/1506123-restorecompletedtransactions) documentation neither explicitly confirm nor deny that the receipt is updated as a part of the restore process. Could this be the expected behavior?
11. Because I had a similar issue with an iOS test app earlier in the year, this may not be a Mac-only situation.

With all of that in mind, does anyone know how to properly handle such a situation? Has anyone had success with restore + refresh?